# Django site goes down for a minute at a time throughout the day

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

Here is a timeline of the uptime for the past 24 hours. The uptime is green and red is the downtime.

[image]

top output:

[image]

Here is Google Analytics for sessions on hourly basis:

[image]

Full up/downtime report:

[image]

Are there any specific configurations that I should be doing?

Comment: Are you the issue is with Django or Apache and not your hosting? I would suggest checking if your server(s) is(are) alive at that time.

Comment: If your logs don't show anything wrong during that time, ask your hosting provider.

Comment: @НазарТопольський Digital Ocean is usually pretty good with uptime

Comment: You need to provide details on how you have configured Apache and mod_wsgi. Some information on what you WSGI application is and does would also be useful. Such as whether it is CPU intensive or I/O bound. If you are always seeing a httpd process with high usage, you could have a problem in your Python code.